# Extract Specific data from json in ansible

Tags: json, ansible, azure-active-directory

I have a big json var, the structure is like this:

```
 {
    "ad_groups": [
        {
            "display_name": "GROUPNAME",
            "group_members": [
                {
                    "account_enabled": BOOL VALUE,
                    "display_name": "NAME",
                    "mail": "EMAIL",
                    "mail_nickname": "NAME",
                    "User_ID": "ID",
                    "user_principal_name": "NAME",
                    "user_type": "MEMBERSHIP VALUE"
                },
                {
                    "account_enabled": BOOL VALUE,
                    "display_name": "NAME",
                    "mail": "EMAIL",
                    "mail_nickname": "NAME",
                    "User_ID": "ID",
                    "user_principal_name": "NAME",
                    "user_type": "MEMBERSHIP VALUE"
                },
                // OTHER MEMBERS
                    .
                    .
                    .
                }
            ],
            "mail": MAIL,
            "mail_enabled": BOOL VALUE,
            "mail_nickname": "NAME",
            "Group_ID": "ID",
            "security_enabled": BOOL VALUE
        },
        {
            // SECOND GROUP DETAILS AS FIRST GROUP
        },
        // OTHER GROUPS with the same format as above
         .
         . 
         . 
    ],
   // SOME MORE DETAILS ON THE TENANT
}
```

I want to extract a list of items from this JSON var. each item name should be the Group_ID value, and the value for that specific item should be all the users IDs (User_ID value), which are members of that specific group.

I tried using the `set_fact` and loops in Ansible to extract the desired fields, but haven't been very successful in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter *json_query* and the function [dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest) does the job

```yaml
  result: "{{ dict(ad_groups|
                   json_query('[].[Group_ID, group_members[].User_ID]')
                  ) }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    ad_groups:
      - Group_ID: GID_1
        display_name: GROUPNAME
        group_members:
          - User_ID: UID_1
            account_enabled: BOOL VALUE
            display_name: NAME
            mail: EMAIL
            mail_nickname: NAME
            user_principal_name: NAME
            user_type: MEMBERSHIP VALUE
          - User_ID: UID_2
            account_enabled: BOOL VALUE
            display_name: NAME
            mail: EMAIL
            mail_nickname: NAME
            user_principal_name: NAME
            user_type: MEMBERSHIP VALUE
        mail: MAIL
        mail_enabled: BOOL VALUE
        mail_nickname: NAME
        security_enabled: BOOL VALUE

    result: "{{ dict(ad_groups|json_query('[].[Group_ID, group_members[].User_ID]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
    GID_1:
    - UID_1
    - UID_2
```

---

If the (simplified) JSON is present in a file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/ad_groups.json 
{"ad_groups": [{"Group_ID": "GID_1", "group_members": [{"User_ID": "UID_1", "user_type": "MEMBERSHIP VALUE"}, {"User_ID": "UID_2", "user_type": "MEMBERSHIP VALUE"}]}]}
```

> {"ad_groups": [{"Group_ID": "GID_1", "group_members": [{"User_ID": "UID_1", "user_type": "MEMBERSHIP VALUE"}, {"User_ID": "UID_2", "user_type": "MEMBERSHIP VALUE"}]}]}

read it

```yaml
    - command: cat /tmp/ad_groups.json
      register: out
```

and declare variables

```yaml
    data: "{{ out.stdout }}"
    result: "{{ dict(data.ad_groups|
                     json_query('[].[Group_ID,
                                     group_members[].User_ID]')) }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  result:
    GID_1:
    - UID_1
    - UID_2
```

If you want to read the file on the controller by lookup convert the string to yaml

```yaml
  data: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/ad_groups.json')|from_yaml }}"
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    data: "{{ out.stdout }}"
    result: "{{ dict(data.ad_groups|
                     json_query('[].[Group_ID,
                                     group_members[].User_ID]')) }}"
    
  tasks:

    - command: cat /tmp/ad_groups.json
      register: out

    - debug:
        var: data

    - debug:
        var: result
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks!

Comment: Vladimir, if the .json is present in a file, e.g. file.json. how would you achieve this w Ansible? Do you cat the file or something?

Comment: Kevin, I added an example.